# Content mode issue in UIImageView when its set to ASpectFill

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I need to load an image in a cell and i get a white border along my image.I'm calling the image from the link and it looks like this.

[image]

but my image looks like

[image]

i'm getting a white border in my image left and right side.Here is my code for image

```
    UIImageView *item=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 115, 130)];

    NSString *imgstring=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",[[mutarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] valueForKey:@"imgurl"]];

    NSURL *imgurl=[NSURL URLWithString:imgstring];

    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgurl]];


    [item setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    item.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    [item setImage:image];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:item];
```

Guidance please...

Comment: I guess your image view frame size is wrong. Try to give some background color to test. Like yellow color to cell background and green color to image view background. Then add those images to here in question, so it will be helpful to the visitor who solves your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by editing webimage becaust it has white background in that u can add the following code to differentiate the image by giving

```
item.backgroundcolor=[UIColor blackcolor];
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 3):

Those white side borders are in the image you posted in your question....that's why they appear in iOS as well.  Open that picture in a photo editor and you will see.

Comment: u can refer the link for example...http:\/\/shop.minora.com.sg\/img\/p\/72-117-large.jpg..this is the original image..u can see there is no white border in that image..

Comment: Um, yeah there is...the link is exactly the same as the one you posted in the question:  300x300 pixels with ~37 pixels of white on each side.

Comment: Image has the white border on both sides.

Comment: Yes there is white border available, open that image in preview software in your mac machine, where in preview set background color black. You will get noticed.